# ModelForm and field generation

Tags: django

When using ModelForm Within forms.py it would save a lot of time, since there is no need to rewrite the whole fields again in forms.

```
class ContactsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

Taking a forms.Form instead would require to define all fields again manually.  Some would prefer this approach due more control.

While  a lot of it is straight forward:

```
models.CharField("First Name",max_length=30, blank=True)
```

becomes

```
forms.CharField(label = _(u'First Name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
```

and `models.TextField(blank=True)` becomes `forms.TextArea(blank=True)` etc...

One field is a bit of a mystery to me how it would be translated in forms, such as:

```
models.ForeignKey(ContactType)
```

How is a dropdownmenu to be defined within forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
contact_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ContactType.objects.all())
```

More about `ModelChoiceField` on Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `forms.ModelChoiceField`